# Read loopback audio on linux

Tags: linux, audio

I'm trying to make an audio visualizer on Linux but I can't seem to find any library that allows me to read the sound levels of the audio of the system. All the libraries I seem to come across seem to either be for reading the microphone or for recording the system audio.

I've tried using `pyaudio` but for some reason, I've only been able to open the microphone and while the program is running the audio coming out of the speakers then gets distorted.

edit: I'm using PulseAudio but I would be fine switching to another sound driver like alsa, etc.

Comment: Which sound system do you use? There are several for linux and they work in different ways.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*